# Relative and absolute path in wordpress doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm improving a word-press web site. I need to include a file to a index WordPress theme, but that happen is really frustrating for me.

If I do in the index.php wordpress theme file, everything is ok:

`include('myfile.php');` // myfile.php is of course in the same folder as index.php.

And the include is done properly.

But, if I try to move "myfile.php" to , for example, the father folder, the next thing should work, but no...:

```
include('../myfile.php');
```

This is for me really frustrating because doesn't have sense...

Next thing I have tried, setting all the absolute path:

`include('http://example.com/myfile.php')` but again, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has shortcuts for this. Try using

```
<?php get_template_part('myfile'); ?>
```

In fact, this is the right way to do an include

Comment: This is really interesting. Because include('myfile') still working, and get_template_part('myfile') is not.

Comment: Weird, Where you have the file?. 'myfile' is inside the template ?

Answer (score 0):

the absolute path must be the path of your file system.

you can try use realpath() php function, which solves the absolute path of the file through the parameter relative path.

see documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php